# How to insert checkbox values one by one in active admin rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to insert checkbox values one by one. Like 1] user_id: 1 , role_id:1 2] user_id:1, role_id:2 using ruby active admin. Please help me.

```
ActiveAdmin.register RoleAssignment do
  permit_params :user_id, :role_id

  index do
    # column :role_id
    column :user_id

    column :role_id do |row|
      column :row
    end

    actions defaults: true do |role|
    end
  end


  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Add/Edit Role" do
      f.input :user_id,  :as => :select, :collection => User.all
      f.input :role_id, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => Role.all
    end
    actions
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below example

```
ActiveAdmin.register RoleAssignment do
  permit_params :user_id, :role_id

  index do
    # column :role_id
    column :user_id

    column :role_id do |row|
      column :row
    end

    actions defaults: true do |role|
    end
  end


  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Add/Edit Role" do
      f.input :user_id,  :as => :select, :collection => User.all
      f.input :role_id, as: :check_boxes, collection: Role.all.map{|x| [x.name, x.id]}
    end
    actions
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks, But I am very new to active admin. Not able to achieve it for checkboxes.

Comment: @SarikaJamdade Have updated my answer, Please check now!

Comment: The value for role_id is going empty.

Comment: This is getting passed 
`=>{"user_id"=>"10", "role_id"=>["", "4", "9"]}`

Comment: @SarikaJamdade Yes, This think does the same thing as you wanted to do.

Comment: The value for `role_id` is going empty in DB.
Getting error: 
`Unpermitted parameter: role_id`

Comment: @SarikaJamdade Now role_id become an array of id So you need to permit an array-like role_id => []